# layout issue after scaling

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml, flex4.5

I have a datagrid that loses its layout after scaling it (by switching between states).

The initialised grid looks as followed:
[image]

but when it is scaled (and rescaled), it looks like this:
[image]

The script that scales it (in the transitions section):

```
<s:Scale scaleXTo="0.01" scaleYTo="0.01" target="{datagrid}" duration="200" />
<s:Scale scaleXTo="1" scaleYTo="1" target="{datagrid}" duration="200" />
```

When I sort the data by something (lets say id), it gets layout back, but I think this is because the datagrid gets refreshed (or something similar to refreshing).

Does anybody know how I can keep the layout after scaling (or refresh the datagrid).

Comment: Just on top of my head, but I would probably call the UpdateDisplayList method of the datagrid after scaling.

Comment: @Angelo I think you mean invalidateDisplayList() which will cause a call to updateDisplayList during the next frame update.  This seems a bit hacky though, doesn't the resize transition serve this purpose more directly?

Answer (score 0):

@shaunhusain, invalidateDisplayList() worked, and with effectEnd at the effect I can call this function.

Now I have another little problem: when there is (only) 1 entry in the grid, it doesn't invalidate properly... 
I get this:
[image: datagrid with one entry]

When there are 2 or more entrys it does work properly...

any idea how to solve this issue?